# Android login app would not accept the NameValuePair params

Tags: php, android, wamp

I am having an issue with my Android login app. The app is to take the username and password and click the button to login and that data will be sent to the URL which is in my Wamp server to search for the name and password of the user using PHP and then encode the data into JSON.

If the user is in the database a success property that has value of 1 in JSON object is return or if they are not in the database a success value of 0 will be return. I place a logcat under the the namevaluepair params that is to post the username and password.

However when I ran the app in the AVD I got back Toast saying connection error and when I checked the logcat I got a error from the namevaluepair that I set under the namevalue pair saying the query was not sent. I don't know what I am doing wrong.

Here is the code

**JsonParser.java**

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair; 
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity; 
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.util.Log;

public class JSONParser {

    private InputStream is = null;
    private JSONObject jObj = null;
    private String json;

    // constructor
    public JSONParser() {

    }

    public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url, List<NameValuePair> params) {

        // Making HTTP request
        try {
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            Log.e("unsupported encoding", e.toString());

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            //e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("client protocol error", e.toString());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            //e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("IO error", e.toString());
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            json = sb.toString();
              is.close();
            Log.e("JSON", json);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // return JSON String
        return jObj;
    }
}
```

**LoginActivity.java**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class LoginActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    private EditText user_name;
    private EditText user_password;
    private Button   login_button;

    // URL to make request
    private static final String URL = "http://10.0.2.2/HMS2/services.php";
    private static final String SUCCESS = "success";

    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject();

    //String object that will store the user input from the edit text widget
    String user;
    String pass;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.login);

        user_name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
        user_password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.userpassword);
        login_button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.login_button);

        //waits for the button to be clicked 
        login_button.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {

        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);

        //gets the user's name from edit text widget and stores it in a variable
        user = user_name.getText().toString();
        user.trim();

        //gets the user's name from the edit text widget and stores it in a variable
        pass = user_password.getText().toString();
        pass.trim();

        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", user));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", pass));
        Log.e("error", "did not get the query");

        //return a JSON object
        json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(URL, params);
        Log.e("error", "did not get back json");

        try {   
            //returns a the key value
            int success = json.getInt(SUCCESS);

            if(success == 1) {
                Toast.makeText(this, " Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Wrong username or password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        } catch(Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Connection problem", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: try to use e.printStrackTrace(); to see what the error is.

Comment: We need to see the exception text

Comment: Can you post your logcat here?

Comment: so ur saying  i must put a try and catch around the namevaluepair

Comment: @ ponraj, here it is http://pastebin.com/qwCSRqRW click on the link

Comment: Are you able to invoke this url from mobile or emulator browser?

Answer (score 0):

The way the code is structured you will see these messages every time it runs.. regardless of error condition. If you want to test for errors then either check the return value of 'getJSONFromUrl' or put the line inside a try/catch.

The message 'End of input at character 0 of' sounds like the server is sending you an empty string. Can you post that code?

Comment: Can you output the value at 'line = reader.readLine()' - I suspect it's empty

Comment: how would i check to see if there is any output value ?

Comment: I'd start with the .php file and use error_log (or equiv) to see what's coming in. Then go to the 'readLine' loop and use Log.e to print out what is being read.